# Caffe web demo error when running a model trained on Digits

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I trained a neural network model  on Digits and it seemed to run fine there.
Then i exported the trained model files and  copied them into a different system running the standard caffe web demo. 
I hoped to just be able to plug those files in and have them run in Caffe but i am getting an error.

Specifically I copied my model into bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel, the  deploy.prototxt into deploy.prototxt, and the  mean.binaryproto into the  ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy file. 
However when I try to run it , it appears to not like the format of the mean.binaryproto file as indicated by the error message:

```
IOError: Failed to interpret file '/home/vagrant/caffe/python/caffe/imagenet/ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy' as a pickle
```

what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to process the mean.binaryproto file from Digits somehow before I use it with caffe?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the `.binaryproto` file to a numpy file.
There is a nice example [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/290) using `caffe.io` and `caffe.proto`.